# Trying to hide an anchor tag using prev() in Jquery

Tags: jquery, hide

I'm trying to hide all links that contain a certain span element

```
<a href="some url"> <span title="show">Show</span></a>

function hideShows(){
    $("span[title='show']").prev().hide();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
      hideShows();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prev()` would select a sibling element, alongside `span`. You want `parent()` or `closest()`.

```
function hideShows(){
  $("span[title='show']").closest('a').hide();
}
```

```js
function hideShows() {
  $("span[title='show']").closest('a').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  hideShows();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="some url"> <span title="show">Show</span>
</a>

<a href="#"><span title="noshow">Leave this alone</span></a>
```

Comment: I believe that would have worked also, which is why I chose the answer, but I ended up with `$("span[title='show']").parent().hide();`

Answer (score 2):

While you're not binding your code inside event handler, you can do this way also:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a:has(span[title='show'])").hide();
});
```

Comment: You are hiding the span, not the anchor tag, if that matter. You can instead use `$("a:has(span[title='show'])").hide();`